# Deferring linking of shared libs

Tags: c++, linux, linker, shared-libraries

If I'm using a shared library in linux, why do I need to link it with -l if the application has to find the library at runtime?

Couldn't I just pass in a dummy .so with the proper function signatures during the linking step and replace it with a real .so at runtime and still have it work properly?

Is there a way to compile an application with just a header file and have the linking take place at runtime?

Comment: Pretty much.  So long as it exposes all the relevant symbol information.

Comment: On Windows you have a .lib file for the linker and a .dll file for the code. A .so file just happens to store both kinds of info in one place.

Answer (score 2):

> If I'm using a shared library in linux, why do I need to link it with -l if the application has to find the library at runtime?

So that the loader knows *which* libraries have to be loaded at runtime.

> Couldn't I just pass in a dummy .so with the proper function signatures during the linking step and replace it with a real .so at runtime and still have it work properly?

Absolutely.

> Is there a way to compile an application with just a header file and have the linking take place at runtime?

Yes, but then it's *your* responsibility to call `dlopen(3)` and `dlsym(3)` yourself to load the libraries and functions.

Comment: <<< Yes, but then it's your responsibility to call dlopen(3) and dlsym(3) yourself to load the libraries and functions. >>> Wouldn't this result in compile time warning about missing symbols? With dlopen you can't directly refer to the symbol by name.

Comment: @Saurabh: You create `static` placeholders for the symbols, and then use `dlsym()` to grab them from the libraries.

Comment: I get that part. But the original question is "Is there a way to compile an application with just a header file", that means the person wants to call functions directly not via function pointers.

Comment: Header files and function pointers are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: I get your point totally. All I am saying is that I don't think questioner wants it this way. Its my feel that he still wants to call the functions by name. Not specify any library at compile time (build time). I might be wrong too :)